# Differential equation of Geodesics of a Cone

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics, geodesic

I am working through Tom Kibbles' Classical Mechanics and am struggling to derive an equation in the excercises on calculus of variations.

The question is to find the geodesics of a cone with semi-vertical angle $\alpha$. Let the cone by specified by the distance r from the vertex and azimuth angle $\phi$ about the axis. You are told to prove:

$$ r\frac{d^2r}{d\phi^2} - 2\left ( \frac{dr}{d\phi } \right )^2 -r^2sin^2\alpha = 0  $$

My Attempt:

I started with $ ds = \sqrt{dr^2 + r^2sin^2(\alpha) d\phi^2} $

Then my function to maximize was $ F = \sqrt{\left ( \frac{dr}{d\phi } \right )^2 + r^2sin^2(\alpha)}$

However the problem I am having is when I calculate $\frac{\partial F}{\partial r} $ and $ \frac{\partial F}{\partial r'}$ I get the answer above without the factor of 2 infront of $r'^2$.

My equations for $\frac{\partial F}{\partial r} $ and $ \frac{\partial F}{\partial r'}$ where:

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} = \frac{rsin^2(\alpha)}{\sqrt{\left ( \frac{dr}{d\phi} \right )^2+r^2sin^2(\alpha)}}$$

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} = \frac{\frac{dr}{d\phi}}{\sqrt{\left ( \frac{dr}{d\phi} \right )^2+r^2sin^2(\alpha)}}$$

Any advice on where I may have made a mistake would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial derivatives $\frac{\partial F}{\partial r},\frac{\partial F}{\partial r'}$ are well developed. The problem perhaps appears on $\frac{d}{d\phi}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial r'}\right)$ which gives

$$
\frac{d}{d\phi}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial r'}\right)=\frac{\sin ^2(\alpha ) r(\phi ) \left(r(\phi ) r''(\phi )-r'(\phi )^2\right)}{\left(\sin ^2(\alpha ) r(\phi )^2+r'(\phi )^2\right)^{3/2}}
$$
so following

$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}-\frac{d}{d\phi}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial r'}\right)=\frac{\sin ^2(\alpha ) r(\phi ) \left(\sin ^2(\alpha ) r(\phi )^2-r(\phi ) r''(\phi )+2 r'(\phi )^2\right)}{\left(\sin ^2(\alpha ) r(\phi )^2+r'(\phi
   )^2\right)^{3/2}}=0
$$

Comment: Thank you very much